# jquery ajax call to webservice in mvc 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net mvc4 project, i have the following markup and jquery in **Index.cshtml** -

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="~/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#btnLogin').click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Content("../../WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld")',
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function () {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
        });

        });
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <button "btnLogin">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

But ajax call returns error. Any help ?

Comment: In your error callback, do `console.log(arguments);` and find out what the error is.

Comment: @Jason P, "undefined"

Comment: Hm... that.. shouldn't be.. anyway, you can also check the network tab of your browser tools for the xhr request. The response should give you some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could because of webservice call it is  conflict between MVC4 Routing Rules

So simple add this line to RouteConfig.cs or Global.asax to ignore conflictions.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*x}", new { x = @".*\.asmx(/.*)?" });
```

I hope this could be useful